# Calculate combinations when sample is equal but one can choose different samples

Tags: combinatorics

At a local lottery where I live you have to guess 5 out of 48 numbers and chances of hitting the jackpot (using *nCr*) are 1 in 1.712.304 (this is a small country), there is another type of play (way expensive) where one can hit the jackpot by only picking 4 numbers (chances climb to 1 in 194.580 using the same formula but with a sample of 4 instead of 5).

Now the question, there is a third way of playing where one can choose 6 (7 or 8) numbers, and if 5 of these numbers go out from the machine you also hit the jackpot (same amount as in the previous cases), how do we calculate these probabilities?

To recap:

**Simple play**; pick 5 from 48 numbers, 5 numbers go out from the machine, if those five number match you win (chances: 1 in 1.712.304)

**Wild card play**; pick 4 from 48 numbers, 5 numbers go out from the machine and if the chosen 4 are contained in that set of 5 you win (chances: 1 in 194.580 <-- **this is wrong**)

**Multiple play**; pick 8 numbers from 48, 5 numbers go out from the machine, if these five numbers are contained in the set of 8 you win (chances: ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your multiple play scenario, when you select 8 numbers from the 48, then you are effectively buying 8 pick 5 (56) "simple play" tickets. So your chances of winning are 56 in 1712304 or approximately 1 in 30577.

You may want to re-think your chances in the wildcard draw. With 4 picked numbers and 1 wildcard, you have effectively bought 44 "simple play" tickets. The formula you used assumes a single ticket in a draw of 4 numbers.

Comment: You are correct in both cases, thanks

Comment: what is the reasoning/formulae behind "8 pick 5 equals 56 simple play" so I can also deduct "7 pick 5 equals ? simple play" (I think it is 21 but arrived to that number from a non related approach)

Comment: It's just the $_nC_r$ formula: $\frac {8!}{5!\times3!}$